# Hide variable get in php htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, get

If I have this URL for example:

```
subdomain.domain.es/specific-path/index.php?b=749372323
```

how do I get the path and hide the rest of the URL, so the result is:

```
subdomain.domain.es/specific-path
```

?

Comment: Why is your PHP-Script written in a way that it needs a `$_GET['b']` if you don't want to pass one?

Comment: Is the `b` value fixed? If so what you want can be done with a redirect in `.htaccess`. If the value is variable and if you don't want it in the path, how do you expect the browser send different values to your script?

Comment: You could hide it with JavaScript.

Comment: I just need read with php once, and hide only in the url, u know? but obviusly i need the variable